# Best way to handle reload-ing of objects, not modules

Tags: python, import, module, reload, ipython

I'm doing a lot of development in IPython where

```
In[3]: from mystuff import MyObject
```

and then I make lots of changes in mystuff.py. In order to update the namespace, I have to do

```
In[4]: reload(mystuff)
In[5]: from mystuff import MyObject
```

Is there a better way to do this? Note that I cannot import MyObject by referencing mystuff directly as with

```
In[6]: import mystuff
In[7]: mystuff.MyObject
```

since that's not how it works in the code. Even better would be to have IPython *automatically* do this when I write the file (but that's probably a question for another time).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps the `ipy_autoreload` extension answers both of your questions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `deep_reload` feature from IPython to do this.

http://ipython.scipy.org/doc/manual/html/interactive/reference.html?highlight=dreload

If you run ipython with the `-deep_reload` parameter to replace the normal `reload()` method.

And if that does not do what you want, it would be possible to write a script to replace all the imported modules in the scope automatically. Fairly hacky though, but it should work ;)

I've just found the `ipy_autoreload` module. Perhaps that can help you a bit. I'm not yet sure how it works but this should work according to the docs:

```
import ipy_autoreload
%autoreload 1
```

Comment: `dreload` still only loads modules.

Comment: @jleedev: the `autoreload` command does exactly what he needs. But you are right, `dreload()` isn't sufficient either.

Comment: This seems to work! The only downside is that it seems to be reloading upon *every* carriage return (i.e. executed line statement in IPython). Otherwise, it's great!

Comment: @reckoner To prevent the reloading on every carriage return, instead of using `%autoreload 1` just type `%autoreload` whenever you need a reload.

Answer (score 0):

If the object is a class or a function, you can use its `__module__` attribute to determine which module to reload:

```
def reload_for(obj):
    module = reload(__import__(obj.__module__, fromlist=True))
    return getattr(module, obj.__name__)

MyClass = reload_for(MyClass)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the %run magic to import the contents of the file you are editing. When you use this to import objects from a file it updates those objects every time you %run it.  This way it's not autoreloading every time you carriage return.